# WPF Rectangle draw border

Tags: wpf

I need to draw dashed border in Grid Cell. I figured it out using Rectangle, but I need to show only rectangle's bottom border without left, right, or top !!

```
    Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
    r.StrokeThickness = 1;
    r.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
    r.StrokeDashArray = new DoubleCollection() { 5 };
    r.StrokeDashCap = PenLineCap.Flat;
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Looks like you can do it with a Rectangle, if you set the Height to 1 and then vertically align it to the bottom like so:

```
<Rectangle Height="1" Stroke="Red" StrokeDashArray="1 2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
```

Comment: But I don't know X2 or Y2 to set them ?? How?

Comment: @Nazaf - Updated my answer. Looks like you can do it with Rectangle :-)

Comment: Thank you!
This is much easier than the line !!

Answer (score 2):

Go to **Properties -> Brush -> Stroke** and select the border-related information:

[image]

Also in the **Properties -> Appearance** section you can do additional customizations over the border/stroke.